# Python refer to class of current code (not extended or inherited class)

Tags: python, class

In the below code I have to refer to `Foo` a second time (i.e. in `super(Foo, self)` Is there anything smarter I can insert, such that if I rename Foo, the other smarter tag doesnt need to be updated? It does not seem like very DRY code.

**Note: I have to specify the starting point for super, the arg can't just be left out because this class gets extended**.

```py
class Foo(Bar):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Foo, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: " the arg can't just be left out because this class gets extended." um, of course it can. The *normal* way to do this is `super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)`, which is equivalent to `super(Foo, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`super()` without arguments in Python 3 is the equivalent of `super(Foo, self)` in your case, and based on your bold description it is also expected to work- even if `Foo` is a parent in subsequent code.

```py
class Foo(Bar):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Should work fine. There are three ways of using `super()`:

```py
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
        
class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        super(Child, self).__init__(a)    
        self.b = b    

class ChildSuper(Parent):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        super().__init__(a)
        self.b = b
        
class ChildClass(Parent):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        Parent.__init__(self, a)
        self.b = b
        
assert Child(1, 2).a == 1
assert ChildSuper(1, 2).a == 1
assert ChildClass(1, 2).a == 1
```

Comment: I thought super() referred to the runtime instance's super, in which case one could get stuck in endless loops (what I learnt when reading how it works). But I just checked https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3135/#id6 and you are right.

Comment: Things can get a little tricky with `super()` sometimes. The method resolution order (MRO) is a key player on how it works and I would recommend looking into it if you are interested in the backend mechanics. Nothing wild, but can help putting 1-and-1 together.

Comment: @run_the_race you aren't making sense. What do you mean "the runtime instance's super"??? `super` is a type, a *class*, it doesn't belong to any runtime instance. The zero-argument form uses a reference to the class *where the method was defined*, this is a bit of implicit "magic" that was added for convenience.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga super is a function, i.e. not a type or a class.. But it does return a class or a type. Its a function that looks at the current instance, the specified (or default) MRO to determine the class returned.

Comment: @run_the_race no, that is *absolutely incorrect*. `super` doesn't return a class, it *returns a `super` object*, because again, `super` is a class itself, i.e. `type(super) is type`. This proxy object then uses the type you pass in (or is implicitly passed in) and the instance you pass in to determine the *next* method in the method resolution order when it delegates the method/attribute you try to access on it

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, sounds like you understand it better than me, will read up on it some day, thanks.

Comment: I think the confusion might be coming from the way that `super` is described in some of the docs. Under the builtin docs it states under [`super()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super): "return a proxy object that delegates method calls to a parent or sibling class of type." So while it's true that`type(super) is type`, it is also true that `print(super())` inside the proper `__init__` will return you `<super: <class 'ChildSuper'>, <ChildSuper object>>`, which is the "proxy object" the docs speaks on (which is of a type `super`).

Comment: Regardless, `super()` is indeed an object, and one that is implemented directly in the Python's C code [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3e1c7167d86a2a928cdcb659094aa10bb5550c4c/Objects/typeobject.c#L8657-L9061)- which explains its "magic" powers that can't be implemented in just Python alone (e.g. programming your own equivalent `super()` object in pure Python).

Comment: @Felipe to be clear, what `super` does doesn't require it be implemented in C, it could be implemented in Python. What couldn't is the *syntactic sugar* of the implicit arguments being passed, which isn't actually in the link you posted, I'm pretty sure, because it is done at the parser level.

Comment: Could you point me towards where the syntactic sugar is implemented? Wouldn't mind learning more.